# Unable to set web3.eth.defaultAccount

Tags: web3js

i'm trying to set the `web3.eth.defaultAccount` with web3js 0.20.5. Somehow setting the default account like `this.web3.eth.defaultAccount = this.web3.eth.accounts[0]` does not work. **Error message**: `this.provider.send is not a function`. I'm able to obtain the address in `this.web3.eth.accounts[0]` though (web3js seems to be working in general).